# How to install wifi drivers on Mac book air?

Tags: 13.10, kernel, macbook

I have a new Mac book air that I (because of the tiny amount of storage on it) booted it from an HHD.  It is the latest version of Ubuntu and it is working great on the laptop.  The only problem is that I need to install a driver for the wifi card but the laptop doesn't have a ethernet port. Is there a way to download the driver some other way?

Answer (score -1):

It requires some manual activities.
Try this http://pavelmanushin.blogspot.ru/2014/04/ubuntu-12.html